# Need help for SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have two tables:
**Attendance Table**

```
ID    student_roll     sem   class_id

1     314              7     1
2     315              7     1
3     316              7     1
4     314              7     2
5     315              7     2
6     314              7     3
7     315              7     3
8     316              7     3
9     314              7     4
10    315              7     4
11    316              7     4
```

**Class Table**

```
class_id    course    t_id    date

1           MC         2      14/3/14
2           MC         2      15/3/14
3           C          2      16/3/14
4           MC         2      17/3/14
```

In the attendance table you can see that roll no. 316 is absent in class_id 2.So suppose i want to count the no of class attended by roll no. 316 in a particular course (Here MC) how can i do so? please help me with the query...Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will return the number of attendance records for a particular student (ie. student roll 316), with respect to a given class (ie. 'MC')

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as ClassCount
  FROM attendance A
       INNER JOIN class_table C
               ON A.class_id = C.class_id
 WHERE A.student_roll = 316
   AND C.course = 'MC'
```